# How to get all the custom content types in MOSS 2007 site or site collection level using powershell script?

Tags: 2007, powershell, content-type, site-collection

I tried using `$site.rootweb.ContentTypes` but it returns all the content types in the site.

I only want to return the custom content types that are created by users.

Please someone help me out.Following are my full code.
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

Function global:Get-SPWebApplication($WebAppURL)
{
 return [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($WebAppURL)
}

#Get the SharePoint Farm. Equallent to : Get-SPFarm commandlet
  $Farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local

#Get All feature of the farm. Equallent to: Get-SPFeature commandlet
  $FarmFeatures= $Farm.FeatureDefinitions

$File =Read-Host("Enter the path of the file")

$WebAppURL = Read-Host("Enter your WebApp URL here")
  $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

#Scan Web Application Features
   #Write the Header to "Tab Separated File"
   "CT Name`t  CT ID`t URL `t CT Group" | out-file $File

foreach($ctype in $WebApp.ContentTypes)
   {
      "$($ctype.Name)   `t      $($ctype.ID)`t     $($WebAppURL)  `t$($ctype.Group)"  | Out-File $File -append
   }

#Get All site collections of the Web Application
   $SitesColl = $webApp.Sites

#Iterate through each site collection/sub-site
   foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
   {

#Iterate through each content type at Site collection level
   foreach($ctype in $site.ContentTypes)
   {
       "$($ctype.Name)   `t      $($ctype.ID)`t     $($site.URL)  `t$($ctype.Group)"  | Out-File $File -append
   }
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {

```
#Iterate through each content type at web level
  foreach($ctype in $web.ContentTypes)
      {
 "$($ctype.Name)   `t      $($ctype.ID)     `t     $($web.URL)  `t$($ctype.Group)"  | Out-File $File -append
```

}
  }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `$site.rootweb.ContentTypes` to get all content types. Then for each one, use the `SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Contains(ContentTypeId)` method ([MS reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltincontenttypeid.contains(v=office.12).aspx)) to check whether the content type is a built in one. If it is not, it must be a custom created one. Like so:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

Function global:Get-SPWebApplication($WebAppURL)
{
    return [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($WebAppURL)
}

Function global:Write-File($contenttype, $url)
{
    if ([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInContentTypeId]::Contains($contenttype.Id))
    {
        "$($contenttype.Name)`t$($contenttype.ID)`t$($url)`t$($contenttype.Group))"  | Out-File $File -append
    }
}

#Get the SharePoint Farm. Equallent to : Get-SPFarm commandlet
$Farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local

#Get All feature of the farm. Equallent to: Get-SPFeature commandlet
$FarmFeatures= $Farm.FeatureDefinitions

$File = Read-Host("Enter the path of the file")

$WebAppURL = Read-Host("Enter your WebApp URL here")
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

#Scan Web Application Features
#Write the Header to "Tab Separated File"
"CT Name`tCT ID`tURL`tCT Group" | out-file $File

foreach($ctype in $WebApp.ContentTypes)
{
    Write-File $ctype $WebAppURL
}

#Get All site collections of the Web Application  
$SitesColl = $webApp.Sites

#Iterate through each site collection/sub-site
foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
{
    #Iterate through each content type at Site collection level
    foreach($ctype in $site.ContentTypes)
    {
        Write-File $ctype $site.Url
    }

    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        #Iterate through each content type at web level
        foreach($ctype in $web.ContentTypes)
        {
            Write-File $ctype $Web.Url
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: It seems `SPBuiltInContentTypeId` does not include ALL built in content types, so this may not give you what you need.

**UPDATE**
Based on the SharePoint 2013 content types [here](http://www.jkevinparker.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-content-types-and.html) I've cobbled this together (I don't know if a similar list exists for 2007 but you can try running this and see what you get back). I've run this on my own farm and the only content types I got back that weren't user-created were SQL Server Reporting Services ones. The list of content types was small enough for me to manually filter these out. So hopefully this script will pretty much give you what you need:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

Function global:Get-SPWebApplication($WebAppURL)
{
    return [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($WebAppURL)
}

Function global:Write-File($contenttype, $url)
{    
    foreach ($ct in $allcts)
    {
        $isCustomCT = $true

        if ($contenttype.Id.ToString() -eq $ct)
        {
            $isCustomCT = $false
            break            
        }        
    }

    if ($isCustomCT -eq $true)
    {
        "$($contenttype.Name)`t$($contenttype.ID)`t$($url)`t$($contenttype.Group))"  | Out-File $File -append
    }    
}

$allcts = "0x"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA0884"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088401"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088402"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088403"`
    ,"0x00A7470EADF4194E2E9ED1031B61DA088404"`
    ,"0x01"`
    ,"0x01000F389E14C9CE4CE486270B9D4713A5D6"`
    ,"0x010018F21907ED4E401CB4F14422ABC65304"`
    ,"0x010019ACC57FBA4146AFA4C822E719824BED"`
    ,"0x010027FC2137D8DE4B00A40E14346D070D52"`
    ,"0x010027FC2137D8DE4B00A40E14346D070D5201"`
    ,"0x01002A2479FF33DD4BC3B1533A012B653717"`
    ,"0x01002CF74A4DAE39480396EEA7A4BA2BE5FB"`
    ,"0x01003A8AA7A4F53046158C5ABD98036A01D5"`
    ,"0x01004613D6562E4C41A7B9DADDAC1689E00D"`
    ,"0x01004C9F4486FBF54864A7B0A33D02AD19B1"`
    ,"0x01004D5A79BAFA4A4576B79C56FF3D0D662D"`
    ,"0x01007CE30DD1206047728BAFD1C39A850120"`
    ,"0x0100807FBAC5EB8A4653B8D24775195B5463"`
    ,"0x010085EC78BE64F9478AAE3ED069093B9963"`
    ,"0x010087D89D279834C94E98E5E1B4A913C67E"`
    ,"0x01009AF87C5C1DF34CA38277FEABCB5018F6"`
    ,"0x01009BE2AB5291BF4C1A986910BD278E4F18"`
    ,"0x0100A2CA87FF01B442AD93F37CD7DD0943EB"`
    ,"0x0100AA27A923036E459D9EF0D18BBD0B9587"`
    ,"0x0100C30DDA8EDB2E434EA22D793D9EE42058"`
    ,"0x0100CA13F2F8D61541B180952DFB25E3E8E4"`
    ,"0x0100DC2417D125A4489CA59DCC70E3F152B2"`
    ,"0x0100F95DB3A97E8046B58C6A54FB31F2BD46"`
    ,"0x0100FBEEE6F0C500489B99CDA6BB16C398F7"`
    ,"0x0101"`
    ,"0x01010000DEC92EFE5D445789D9FE4A3225A381"`
    ,"0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC1"`
    ,"0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811"`
    ,"0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE8110003D357F861E29844953D5CAA1D4D8A3B"`
    ,"0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F"`
    ,"0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F0054AD6EF48B9F7B45A142F8173F171BD1"`
    ,"0x0101000F1C8B9E0EB4BE489F09807B2C53288F0054AD6EF48B9F7B45A142F8173F171BD10003D357F861E29844953D5CAA1D4D8A3A"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F3851066"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106601"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106602"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106604"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106605"`
    ,"0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F3851068"`
    ,"0x01010058DDEB47312E4967BFC1576B96E8C3D4"`
    ,"0x010100629D00608F814DD6AC8A86903AEE72AA"`
    ,"0x010100734778F2B7DF462491FC91844AE431CF"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00291D173ECE694D56B19D111489C4369D"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B006973ACD696DC4858A76371B2FB2F439A"`
    ,"0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F214"`
    ,"0x010100A2E3C117A0C5482FAEE3D57C48CB042F"`
    ,"0x010100B4CBD48E029A4AD8B62CB0E41868F2B0"`
    ,"0x010100C5033D6CFB8447359FB795C8A73A2B19"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39004C1F8B46085B4D22B1CDC3DE08CFFB9C"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39004C1F8B46085B4D22B1CDC3DE08CFFB9C0055EF50AAFF2E4BADA437E4BAE09A30F8"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900796F542FC5E446758C697981E370458C"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900B46186789C3140CC85BE610336E86BBB"`
    ,"0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900FD0E870BA06948879DBD5F9813CD8799"`
    ,"0x010100E8711F0F931646FA949751442A907B22"`
    ,"0x010100F8EF98760CBA4A94994F13BA881038FA"`
    ,"0x010100FDA260FD09A244B183A666F2AE2475A6"`
    ,"0x010101"`
    ,"0x010102"`
    ,"0x010104"`
    ,"0x010105"`
    ,"0x010106"`
    ,"0x010107"`
    ,"0x010108"`
    ,"0x010109"`
    ,"0x01010901"`
    ,"0x01010A"`
    ,"0x01010B"`
    ,"0x0102"`
    ,"0x0102004F51EFDEA49C49668EF9C6744C8CF87D"`
    ,"0x01020072BB2A38F0DB49C3A96CF4FA85529956"`
    ,"0x0102007DBDC1392EAF4EBBBF99E41D8922B264"`
    ,"0x0103"`
    ,"0x0104"`
    ,"0x0105"`
    ,"0x0106"`
    ,"0x0107"`
    ,"0x0108"`
    ,"0x0108003365C4474CAE8C42BCE396314E88E51F"`
    ,"0x010801"`
    ,"0x01080100C9C9515DE4E24001905074F980F93160"`
    ,"0x010802"`
    ,"0x0109"`
    ,"0x010A"`
    ,"0x010B"`
    ,"0x010C"`
    ,"0x0110"`
    ,"0x0111"`
    ,"0x0116"`
    ,"0x0120"`
    ,"0x012001"`
    ,"0x012002"`
    ,"0x012004"`
    ,"0x0120D5"`
    ,"0x0120D520"`
    ,"0x0120D520A8"`
    ,"0x0120D520A808"


#Get the SharePoint Farm. Equallent to : Get-SPFarm commandlet
$Farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local

#Get All feature of the farm. Equallent to: Get-SPFeature commandlet
$FarmFeatures= $Farm.FeatureDefinitions

$File = Read-Host("Enter the path of the file")

$WebAppURL = Read-Host("Enter your WebApp URL here")
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

#Scan Web Application Features
#Write the Header to "Tab Separated File"
"CT Name`tCT ID`tURL`tCT Group" | out-file $File

foreach($ctype in $WebApp.ContentTypes)
{
    Write-File $ctype $WebAppURL
}

#Get All site collections of the Web Application  
$SitesColl = $webApp.Sites

#Iterate through each site collection/sub-site
foreach($Site in $SitesColl)
{
    #Iterate through each content type at Site collection level
    foreach($ctype in $site.ContentTypes)
    {
        Write-File $ctype $site.Url
    }

    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        #Iterate through each content type at web level
        foreach($ctype in $web.ContentTypes)
        {
            Write-File $ctype $Web.Url
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But i cant able to use SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Contains(ContentTypeId) in MOSS 2007 environment. Can you please explain it further?

Comment: Update your question with your full script as it is at the moment, then I can help further.

Comment: i have updated my question with my full script. Now can you help me where i can make changes to get only the custom content type.

Comment: Added updated code to my answer, but see the caveat...

Comment: Added further update that should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. now i got the exact output what i need. thank you very much Submits...